# Twitter API: merge retweeted_by_me into user_timeline

Tags: php, twitter

I can access both methods using the twitteroauth php library. Just thinking of how to merge the two feeds together in a smart way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix to it in the Google Group. You have to add include_rts=true to the end of the user_timeline request. Just adding it here in case someone is looking for it!